# Bootstrap Carousel is not responding

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I have been trying to add a carousel to my landing page and come out with a problem, i am able to see the first image of the carousel but the template literally does not slide to the next image. I have copied the template from bootstrap-carousel, i can see the navigators, ***data-bs-interval*** not responding, too. My Bootstrap version is 5.1.3. I even tried to add references for Jquery even though I know it's not required. Thank you in advance.

References:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML and CSS codes;

```css
#carouselExampleCaptions img{
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
//alignment and resizing
}
```

```html
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide " data-bs-ride="carousel"  data-bs-interval="2000">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="/jpg/wood_12.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Özel Üretim</h5>
            <p>Masa tasarımı ve boyutlarını sizin tercihinize göre yapılandırıyoruz</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/jpg/wood_10.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/jpg/wood_11.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to a Bootsrap 5 page that I currently have open and the slides do seem to work OK. I haven't changed anything except to remove `d-none` from the `carousel-caption`'s. I am fairly sure that wasn't preventing the slideshow though.

`data-bs-interval` needs to go on each slide. On each of the Divs which have `class="carousel-item"`

Answer (score 0):

I just copy pasted your code to a codepen and it seems working fine.

are you sure you added links to jquery, bootstrap css and bootstrap js to ur project?

You can check the [codepen here](https://codepen.io/DarkForest144/pen/VwrVjBp)

```css
#carouselExampleCaptions img {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  //alignment and resizing
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide " data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="2000">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564419320408-38e24e038739?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Özel Üretim</h5>
        <p>Masa tasarımı ve boyutlarını sizin tercihinize göre yapılandırıyoruz</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1646121575186-fe136178cff2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxM3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1646100960029-967036496807?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxN3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
</div>
```